# writing/reading from network while serving a block device request

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I modified a block device driver for a ramdisk (similar to the one here: http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/02/device-drivers-disk-on-ram-block-drivers/) so that driver reads/writes from the network. I basically removed `memcpy` and replaced it with an in-kernel network socket read/write.

And here is what I get: a warning that irqs are disabled. The warning is thrown from the line `WARN_ON_ONCE(in_irq() || irqs_disabled());` inside the function `_local_bh_enable_ip`.

My understanding is that what I did should work since all disk requests are queued in the work queue supplied in the `gendisk`. And job handler (supplied when `blk_init_queue()` is called) will be called from the typical kernel context, where irqs should be enabled. But I guess I was wrong.

Anyone can help with a work-around?

Here is the top part of the stack trace spelled out by the kernel:

```
[  697.480153]  [<ffffffff8105931f>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7f/0xc0
[  697.480159]  [<ffffffff8105937a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[  697.480166]  [<ffffffff8106172a>] local_bh_enable+0x7a/0xa0
[  697.480175]  [<ffffffff815974b3>] lock_sock_nested+0x53/0x60
[  697.480183]  [<ffffffff815eedfc>] tcp_sendmsg+0x2c/0xe60
[  697.480197]  [<ffffffff8134226c>] ? vsnprintf+0x35c/0x640
[  697.480207]  [<ffffffff81618331>] inet_sendmsg+0x61/0xb0
[  697.480216]  [<ffffffff81592912>] sock_sendmsg+0xd2/0xf0
[  697.480226]  [<ffffffff8133708e>] k_send+0x6e/0x80
[  697.480236]  [<ffffffffa02b34ee>] ramdevice_read+0x5e/0xd0 [dor]
[  697.480244]  [<ffffffffa02b31a3>] rb_request+0x133/0x1b0 [dor]
```

Update: 
As Peter L. Suggested. I changed it so that the socket read/write is done in a tasklet. And this is what I got:

```
[  138.711263]  [<ffffffff816dbedc>] __schedule_bug+0x4d/0x59
[  138.711266]  [<ffffffff816f27b8>] __schedule+0x628/0x6b0
[  138.711269]  [<ffffffff816f2b59>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[  138.711273]  [<ffffffff816f12d5>] schedule_timeout+0x1e5/0x250
[  138.711276]  [<ffffffff81045cd9>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x9/0x10
[  138.711280]  [<ffffffff815d1361>] sk_wait_data+0xd1/0xe0
[  138.711284]  [<ffffffff8107fd70>] ? add_wait_queue+0x60/0x60
[  138.711286]  [<ffffffff816277f2>] tcp_recvmsg+0x502/0xb60
[  138.711289]  [<ffffffff8164e7fb>] inet_recvmsg+0x6b/0x80
[  138.711292]  [<ffffffff8164e871>] ? inet_sendmsg+0x61/0xb0
[  138.711294]  [<ffffffff815ca180>] sock_recvmsg+0xe0/0x100
[  138.711299]  [<ffffffff8105b30a>] ? console_unlock+0x1a/0x30
[  138.711302]  [<ffffffffa027f42b>] k_recv+0x6b/0x80 [ksocket]
[  138.711306]  [<ffffffffa02a066d>] ramdevice_read+0x7d/0xd0 [dor]
[  138.711309]  [<ffffffffa02a0360>] my_tasklet_func+0x60/0x80 [dor]
[  138.711312]  [<ffffffff81062ae4>] tasklet_action+0x64/0xe0
[  138.711315]  [<ffffffff81062620>] __do_softirq+0xc0/0x240
[  138.711318]  [<ffffffff810627d8>] run_ksoftirqd+0x38/0x50
[  138.711321]  [<ffffffff8108804d>] smpboot_thread_fn+0xfd/0x180
[  138.711325]  [<ffffffff81087f50>] ? lg_global_lock+0x70/0x70
[  138.711328]  [<ffffffff8107f1b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
[  138.711332]  [<ffffffff8107f0f0>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0xb0/0xb0
[  138.711335]  [<ffffffff816fc82c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[  138.711339]  [<ffffffff8107f0f0>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0xb0/0xb0
```

Comment: Try scheduling your work in a tasklet (tasklet_schedule(&my_socket_work_tasklet).

Comment: Please see update above.

Comment: Maybe you could do this with a kernel thread instead.

Comment: How do you suggest doing that? can you please be more specific? do you mean creating a new kernel thread for each request? Would not that be too inefficient? If you mean one kernel daemon? how can we guarantee decent synchronization between the producer and consumer? I have seen a tutorial in the past about producer/consumer synchronization, but it was very buggy!

Comment: I was thinking maybe a single thread for read and one for write and synchronizing with semaphore or some other mechanism between the producer and consumer.  If you have code snippets for your modifications we might be able to help more.

Comment: I will put up my stripped out experimentation code on bitbucket and share it publicly.

Comment: here is it: https://bitbucket.org/hebbo_pub/networkblockdevice

Comment: I was able to build ksocket.ko.  I'll try to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Please pull the code one more time...I have updated it with some fixes  on Wednesday Sep 18th 5:40 MT. Now, I can add the block device, invoke mkswap on it. But when I add it to swap space (swapon /dev/rb) the module crashes with inconsistent reply message size.

Comment: I built ksocket and disk-on-ram, but that server requires too much editing.  I'll try to invoke this operation some other way.

Comment: I have fixed the server ... please pull the latest code.

Comment: Now I did some code changes and got somewhere. However, I am having this issue now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891005/why-do-a-socket-reads-more-data-than-what-is-actually-sent